# What would cause text not to display within an amx command button in oracle's mobile application framework?

Tags: java, android, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

The issue with text not being displayed in the command button element started when Google updated its WebView to version 80.0.3987.99. Disabling chrome and resetting factory default settings and then re-enabling google chrome works, however, once they release a new update it changes the WebView again causing the missing text issue again. I am looking to find a more permanent solution to fix the issue. Below is an example of what my code looks like for the button.

```
<amx:commandButton text="  Logged in  " inlineStyle="background-color:#00fa1d; border: 1px solid #0069aa; border-radius:9px; color: white;"></amx:commandButton>
```

[image: image showing no text in buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only available solution I found was to recreate the command buttons as command links which I have styled to look like command buttons. The style is the same and the functionality has been restored.

Change Command Button:

```
    <amx:commandButton text="  Logged in  " inlineStyle="background-color:#00fa1d; border: 1px solid #0069aa; border-radius:9px; color: white;" rendered = "#{preferenceScope.application.ebs.loggedIn}"></amx:commandButton>
```

To Command Link:

```
        <amx:commandLink text="  Logged in  " inlineStyle="background-color:#00fa1d; border: 1px solid #0069aa; border-radius:9px; color: white; padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; text-decoration:none !important;" rendered = "#{preferenceScope.application.ebs.loggedIn}"></amx:commandLink>
```